# How to use express `res.sendFile()` in firebase cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

As per Firebase documentation, Cloud Functions need to end with `res.send()`, `res.end()` or `res.redirect()`. When I use `res.sendFile()` to send the content of a file, the console log show more than 1 invocation (actually 4-5 innovations).

So, what's proper way to use `res.sendFile()` in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be worth chaining a HTTP status code along with `sendFile()` to infer that the function has completed successfully, and therefore stop it from being invoked again:

```
res.status(200).sendFile(...)
```

The [documentation on terminating HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions) provides an example with just `send()`:

> ```
> const formattedDate = moment().format(format);
> console.log('Sending Formatted date:', formattedDate);
> res.status(200).send(formattedDate);
> ```

But also [the majority of the calls to `send()`](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/search?q=res.send), or other examples like [`json()`](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/ad474614dbe761b1301d958d93c0033275ef457c/username-password-auth/functions/index.js#L63) within the [Cloud Functions for Firebase Sample Library](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) all use `status()` alongside.

Comment: I have tested with `res.status(200).sendFile(...)` and it still invoke multiple calls in the Firebase console log.

Comment: That's strange, does it invoke the function again only after the response is sent? Does the same thing happen if you use `send()` or `redirect()` instead?

Comment: I am not too if the multiple invocation has anything to do with generating an AMP page (which may be CDN cached) on Chrome browser...

Comment: It could be, any traffic to the function's HTTPS endpoint will trigger it. You can handle invalid invocations by sending a [payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request) with valid traffic (from your app) and then checking for that payload at the very start of the function and exiting if it doesn't exist (it won't exist for invocations from other traffic).

Comment: @Grimthorr I'm trying to return a success.html file which is my public directory but I cant seem to get it to work. What is the path you supplied inside sendFile(...) ?